# Ansible when for multiple tasks

Tags: ansible

Im looking at some ansible examples and found the [following example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement):

```
tasks:
    - shell: echo "I've got '{{ foo }}' and am not afraid to use it!"
      when: foo is defined

    - fail: msg="Bailing out. this play requires 'bar'"
      when: bar is undefined
```

Lets say we only want to run any of the following tasks if "somevar is defined"

```
tasks:
    - shell: echo "1"
      when: foo is defined

    - shell: echo "2"
      when: barone is defined

    - shell: echo "3"
      when: bartwo is defined

    - shell: echo "4"
      when: bar is undefined
```

Is this possible to only add the "when" one time for multiple tasks? 
I want to avoid the following situation

```
tasks:
    - shell: echo "1"
      when: 
        -foo is defined
        -somevar is defined

    - shell: echo "2"
      when: 
        -barone is defined
        -somevar is defined
```

note multiple times the same when (imagine a list of 100 tasks).

Comment: Well, I cannot "*note multiple times the same when*" because the situation is not present in your question. So it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @techraf maybe my wording is wrong but what I ment is that i only want to run some tasks if a condition is met, else skip those tasks. But i do not want to write a when for each task as there can be 100 tasks dependend on the when. so when the when changes i dont want to change 100 whens.